Formula to generate a specific sequence
I'm not a mathematician, but lately, I've been watching many math videos on YouTube, and I have an idea I can't find any reference. The problem is:
Given that four agents ordered descendants, giving some work to the agents, I want to give more work to the agent in the first place, followed by the agent in the second place, and so on.
The sequence generated for these four agents is described in the table for the first ten units of time (t):



Time (t)
Agent




1
1


2
1


3
2


4
1


5
2


6
3


7
1


8
2


9
3


10
4



This sequence should repeat forever, meaning the t=11 -> Agent 1, t=12 -> Agent 1, t=13 -> Agent 2 ... etc.
With this distribution, the agent ranked one will perform the work less than 50% of the time, the ranked two around 37% of the time, etc. The higher the ranking, the more work will be assigned to them.
I'm sure I'm not the first to think about this. Are there any studies about this specific sequence?
I want to extract a formula where I can provide the number of agents, the time (t), and the output, which should be the agent that will be active in the slot. As examples:
f(4, 2) = Agent 1
f(4, 10) = Agent 4
f(4, 11) = Agent 1
f(4, 12) = Agent 1
f(4, 13) = Agent 2
f(4, 20) = Agent 4

Of course, I can have as many agents as I want. It could be five or ten or fifteen. The formula should work for any number of agents.
Of course, I can do this with a program. The idea is not to be dependent on a programming language, meaning that if I implement this in Python, for example, and someone else in JavaScript, there could be a bug in the code that could lead to different results; that is why I would like to be a mathematical formula.
Can anyone here point me in the right direction or help me?
Paulo Aboim Pinto

If you want this function to be programming-language agnostic, why are you asking this question on a site for the programming language Mathematica? Perhaps you meant to post this on [math.se]?

If the aim is just to get the value of the sequence at a certain point then this could be done without an explicit formula/expression for the sequence. For example:
seq[m_, n_]:= Modulel{t= Join@@
Table [Range[j], {j, m}]},t[[Mod[n,
PolygonalNumber[m], 1]]]]

Some examples:
Grid[{{4, #}, seq[4, #]}& /@Range[11,
20]]
Grid[{{6, #}, seq[6, #]}& /@ Range[1000,
1021]]


You can use FindSequenceFunction. This will produce a complicated sum of cosines that can be simplified but gets harder as the number of agents increases.
I agree with @march comment. If the aim is purely mathematical then Mathematics Stack Exchange is advised. If it is to programmatically achieve result then this can be done in Mathematica/Wolfram Language. The above is an approach.
Apologies for errors.
Wishing all users a safe New Years Eve and a 2025 with more positives than negatives.
✌️ 
Post script
For comparison using FindSequenceFunction on the example in OP:
a[n_] := 
  FindSequenceFunction[
   Table[Splice[Join @@ Table[Range[j], {j, 4}]], 2], n];
w = FullSimplify[TrigToExp[a[z]]]
f[x_] := w /. z -> x
Show[Plot[f[z], {z, 1, 20}], 
 DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 1, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> {0, 5}]



The scheduling of $n$ agents looks like a list of lists where the length increases by 1 each time until we hit $n$, and start over:
$$
\{1\},\{1,2\},...,\{1,...j\},...\{1,...n\}\}
$$
So the period of the scheduling is
$$
\mathrm{L(n)} = \sum_{j=1}^n j = \frac{1}{2} n (1+n)
$$
len[nAgents_] := 1/2 nAgents (1 + nAgents)

To figure out which run $j$ $\{1,...,j\}$ we are in, we take the ceiling of the inverse positive function of $\mathrm{L(n)}$
jRunNumber[index_] := 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 index]) // Ceiling

And finally we subtract the previous jRunNumber lengths from the index mod $\mathrm{len}(n)$ with offest 1.
f[nAgents_, index_] := With[{mod = Mod[index, len@nAgents, 1]},
  mod - len@(jRunNumber[mod] - 1)
  ]


Or as one function put together:
f[nAgents_, index_] := Module[{len, m, j},

  len = 1/2 nAgents (1 + nAgents);
  m = Mod[index, len, 1];
  j = Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 m])];

  (1/2) (1 - j) j + m
  ]

And putting this all together as a mathematical formula, using the standard $\bmod$ instead of the offset-1 $\bmod$
$$
L = \frac{1}{2} n (1+n) \\
m = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} L & L \mid i \\
i \bmod L & L \nmid i
\end{array}\right\} \\ 
j =\left\lceil \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{8 m+1}-1\right)\right\rceil\\
\boxed{f(i,n)  =\frac{1}{2} (1-j)j + m}
$$
So for example:
Grid[{{4, #}, f[4, #]} & /@ Range[11, 20]]
Grid[{{6, #}, f[6, #]} & /@ Range[1000, 1021]]



this is a variant of my answer where you explicitly use formula for nth Triangular number  (Polygonal number) and use Ceiling of the function that takes triangular number and returns index. The latter, though, able to rendered as an expression seems less efficient than Part. Of course, I accept that this may be what OP wants as a formula. I think taking part of a vector is part of most programming languages.

on reflection this will do better for arbitrary number of agents and index, + 1

@ubpdqn yes sorry, I realize the initial derivation is basically the same for my answer compared to yours. I just wanted to define f such that I don't have to generate the single period schedule list Table [Range[j], {j, nAgents}]. From a performance perspective, generating that list doesn't really matter much until you have really big nAgents, and it does make f a lot simpler to understand so your answer is probably better for most cases.

no apology required. You provided both a formula and an implementation that doesn’t need generating the vector to take part of. It is numerical and would probably achieve the language agnosticism OP wants.

Happy New Year!

To you as well! Wishing you a great year $\sum _i^9 i^3= 2025$
